# Getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations$Mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

When i am trying to create junit for controller i am getting below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations$Mock
```

my pom.xml :

```
org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4
org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3
```

controller:

```
@Autowired
ELKLoggerService loggerService; 
private UUID correlationId = UUID.randomUUID();

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<ResponseType<List<ComEntity>>> getAllComs(@RequestHeader String emailId, @RequestHeader String userName) {
String message = "ComController :: getAllComs :: " + "correlationId : " + correlationId.toString();
loggerService.info(message, correlationId.toString());
return comService.getAllComs(emailId, userName, correlationId.toString());
}
```

Comment: please check the JUnit dependency in your pom.xml file.

Comment: Added dependencies

Comment: please change the version and try once.

Comment: keep the both versions same.

Comment: tried with changing versions but getting same error

Comment: Could you add a stack trace and some code snippets as well?

Comment: @SabinaOrazem Added Controller for which i am creating Junit with Mockito.

Answer (score 9):

Below is dependency compatibility.

```
Mockito                     PowerMock
1.10.8+                     1.6.2+
1.9.5-rc1 - 1.9.5           1.5.0 - 1.5.6
1.9.0-rc1 & 1.9.0           1.4.10 - 1.4.12
1.8.5                       1.3.9 to 1.4.9
1.8.4                       1.3.7 & 1.3.8 
1.8.3                       1.3.6
1.8.1 & 1.8.2               1.3.5
1.8                         1.3
1.7                         1.2.5
```

This may fix issue

Comment: here is the official source of the up-to-date table: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions